# Alinhar imagem de acordo com o container usando CSS

Tags: css

Tenho um cadastro de banner que terá tamanhos fixos, então eu quero adicionar um qrcode que será gerado pelo sistema nesta imagem, juntamente com a foto do usuário.
Eu tenho esta situação :

```
#carimbo-foto{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:0
}


#banner{
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    top:  0%;
}

#carimbo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 38%;
    margin-left:-64px;
    margin-top:-73px;  
    z-index:1
}

#qrcode{
    position: absolute;
    left: 51%;
    top: 78%;
    margin-left:-64px;
    margin-top:-73px;  
    z-index:1
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="carimbo-foto">

<img src="/Content/imagens/user8-128x128.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="carimbo" alt="" width="90" height="98">
<img src="/Content/imagembanner/banner_novo.png" class="img-responsive" id="banner" alt="" width="560" height="315">
<img src="/Content/qrcode/1.png" class="img-responsive" id="qrcode" alt="" width="80" height="80">

</div>
```

Resultado atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dei uma brisada na 1º resposta pq eu tava fazendo no fiddle, e a tela de resiltado é pequena num vi direito com ia ficar na tela normal... Mas acho que é isso... Vlw espero que ajude...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom se tá colocando o `#qrcode` e `#carimbo` em `position:absolute`, aí ele não respeitará `.carimbo-foto`, outra que carimbo-foto é uma `classe` e se tá declarando como identificador no `css`.

```css
.carimbo-foto{
position:relative;
height: 315px;
width:560px;
}
#carimbo{
position:absolute;
right: 11px;
top: -15px;
}
#qrcode{
position:absolute;
right: 11px;
bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carimbo-foto">

<img src="http://img.vmessages.com/en/funny/35.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="carimbo" alt="" width="90" height="98">
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/bandeira-horizontal-de-cloudscape-43923748.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="banner" alt="" width="560" height="315">
<img src="http://cdnqrcgde.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/jpeg.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="qrcode" alt="" width="80" height="80">

</div>
```

Ao meu ver um caminho  mais fácil era definir a imagem do banner como background da div carimbo foto, porém se a imagem não for estática complica um pouco...

Vê se ajuda esse exemplo...

Comment: muito grato a ajuda!

Comment: @itasouza Disponha, caso alguma das respostas tenha sido útil, poderia validá-la clicando no icon verde abaixo das setas de avaliação... Vlw ;)